# Kusto:How to convert list columns to rows

Tags: kql

I have one columns in Table column type is string.

```
["2021-03-18T08:49:08.4670000Z","2021-03-18T13:41:59.3230000Z","2021-03-18T13:46:59.2390000Z","2021-03-18T15:00:13.1960000Z","2021-03-18T16:19:47.0000000Z","2021-03-18T16:26:49.8480000Z","2021-03-18T17:06:49.7910000Z","2021-03-18T18:19:44.8760000Z","2021-03-18T19:34:44.8710000Z","2021-03-18T19:48:01.7160000Z","2021-03-18T20:23:01.6540000Z","2021-03-18T20:56:49.7960000Z","2021-03-18T22:21:49.7880000Z","2021-03-18T23:44:47.6500000Z","2021-03-19]
```

IwWant to save this list as rows;
like:

```
Start_time
2021-03-18T08:49:08.4670000Z
2021-03-18T13:41:59.3230000Z
2021-03-18T13:46:59.2390000Z
```

I have try few things but it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn it into dynamic and use mv-expand:

```
datatable(Values:string)['["2021-03-18T08:49:08.4670000Z","2021-03-18T13:41:59.3230000Z","2021-03-18T13:46:59.2390000Z","2021-03-18T15:00:13.1960000Z","2021-03-18T16:19:47.0000000Z","2021-03-18T16:26:49.8480000Z","2021-03-18T17:06:49.7910000Z","2021-03-18T18:19:44.8760000Z","2021-03-18T19:34:44.8710000Z","2021-03-18T19:48:01.7160000Z","2021-03-18T20:23:01.6540000Z","2021-03-18T20:56:49.7960000Z","2021-03-18T22:21:49.7880000Z","2021-03-18T23:44:47.6500000Z","2021-03-19"]']
| extend Values =todynamic(Values)
| mv-expand Values to typeof(datetime)
```

Please note that the last value in your example was missing a closing qoute. As a side note, it would be better to type the column as dynamic in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for solution .but this is not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have try following way

- convert dynamic columns to string

  | mv-expand start_time =split(start_time, ",") to typeof(string)
  | mv-expand end_time =split(end_time, ",") to typeof(string)
- Convert String to datetime.

  project todatetime(start_time), todatetime(end_time), Events;
  q2